# Android platform supported hardware architecture

Tags: android

How to check whether a particular hardware architecture is supported by android?

What are the android supported architectures?

Comment: Define more what you mean by hardware architecture: Instruction Set ? Peripherals devices?

Comment: Do you mean: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-feature-element.html#hw-features

Comment: By hardware architecture I mean architectures like x86 etc.

Comment: Android being a Linux kernel, you could parse `/proc/cpuinfo`

Comment: You may want to look at this blog post by Roman10 http://www.roman10.net/how-to-get-cpu-information-on-android/

Answer (score 2):

*Joshua J. Drake*, author of [Android Hacker's Handbook](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/111860864X) mentions about supported architectures as of March 7th 2013:

> Android supports at least 4 architectures
>
> 1. ARM (The Lion’s share of devices out there…)
> 2. x86 (Google TV devices, tablets, phones)
> 3. MIPS
> 4. PowerPC
>      Really anything Linux will run on...

In addition, [in this wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_%28operating_system%29#Hardware), it tells about [Android-x86](http://www.android-x86.org/) project and [Freescale's i.MX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/I.MX#Android) support.
In the future, no one can guess what else will be supported for Android OS.

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation for the Android NDK](http://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/abis.html#sa) specifies the ABIs (application binary interfaces) to which object files built by the NDK need to comply in order for the operating system and machine code to have a common language. The second column lists the instruction sets supported.